# Different outputs for different number of printf calls

Tags: c, struct, printf, malloc, nan

I am quite new in C and I have a strange problem with my code.

I am trying to create an array of `struct` as part of another array of `struct`.

I am obtaining different outputs when the number of `printf` function is different. I have two cases, one is correct but the other is incorrect.

I do not understand why a simple call of an extra `printf` should change the result.

This is my code with the incorrect result, here I obtain "x velocity=-nan"

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct vect3d1
{
    double *x,*y,*z;
};

struct block
{ 
   int ibl;
   struct vect3d1 *velocity;
};

void create_time(struct block *blocks,int Nsteps,int nb);


int main()
{

struct block *blocks;
int nb,i,t,Nsteps;
Nsteps=30;
nb=3;
blocks=calloc(nb, sizeof(struct block));
for (i=0;i<nb;i++){
        for(t=0;t<Nsteps;t++){

blocks[i].velocity=(struct vect3d1 *)malloc(Nsteps*sizeof(struct vect3d1));
blocks[i].velocity[t].x=NULL;
blocks[i].velocity[t].y=NULL;
blocks[i].velocity[t].z=NULL;

}
}

create_time(blocks,Nsteps,nb);

free(blocks);
}

void create_time(struct block *blocks,int Nsteps,int nb){

int i,t;
double u;

for (i=0;i<nb;i++){
    for(t=0;t<Nsteps;t++){
        u=0.5+t;
        blocks[i].velocity[t].x=&u;
//          printf("u %lf \n",u);
        printf("velocity x=%lf \n",blocks[i].velocity[t].x);

}
}


}
```

You can notice that a line in the function `create_time` is commented, when it is not commented the result is correct.

Just for clarify, if the function `create_time` is:

```
void create_time(struct block *blocks,int Nsteps,int nb){

int i,t;
double u;

for (i=0;i<nb;i++){
    for(t=0;t<Nsteps;t++){
        u=0.5+t;
        blocks[i].velocity[t].x=&u;
//          printf("u %lf \n",u);
        printf("velocity x=%lf \n",blocks[i].velocity[t].x);

}
}


}
```

i obtain :

```
"velocity x=-nan"
```

When the function is:

```
void create_time(struct block *blocks,int Nsteps,int nb){

int i,t;
double u;

for (i=0;i<nb;i++){
    for(t=0;t<Nsteps;t++){
        u=0.5+t;
        blocks[i].velocity[t].x=&u;
            printf("u %lf \n",u);
        printf("velocity x=%lf \n",blocks[i].velocity[t].x);

}
}


}
```

I obtain:

```
"u 0.5"

"velocity x=0.5"
...
```

and so on.

I have added the line just to verify the variable `u`, then I realized that adding it the output of `printf` is changed.

What is happen? Why the output of `printf` is changed?

Comment: `x` is a pointer `double *x`. You need to deference it. `*blocks[i].velocity[t].x);
`. Turn on compiler warnings and resolve each warning.

Comment: `blocks[i].velocity` allocation should be outside the `t` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
  printf("velocity x=%lf \n",blocks[i].velocity[t].x);
```

you do not pass a `double` but a pointer to a `double`, although a `double`  is expected. This invokes the infamous undefined behaviour. Do not do this.

Also I wonder why the compiler did not warn you abut this. You might like to pump up the compiler's waning level. For GCC add the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` when compiling to do so.

To fix this change it to be

```
  printf("velocity x=%lf \n", *blocks[i].velocity[t].x);
```

So to answer your question:

> What is happen? Why the output of printf is changed?

Welcome to the mysterious world of Undefined Behaviour. ;)

---

Apart from this, please be aware that this line

```
  blocks[i].velocity[t].x=&u;
```

is dangerous, as you assign the address of a variable *local* to the function to a pointer which mostly likely will be used after then function has been left.

It does *not* point to valid memory any more once the function is left.

Dereferencing it then will invoke undefined behaviour, take care.

---

As a final friendly note: Do yourself and your fellow coders which have to read your code a favour and *indent code properly*. This is debugging for free. I have the strong impression that [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291531/different-outputs-for-different-number-of-printf-calls/54291620#comment95403679_54291531) dues to the messy indention of the code as shown.

Comment: Thank you very much! :D